# Mathematica Syntax - Mixing commands with text

Tags: syntax

Simple question but couldn't find answer anywhere..

I'm trying to write a coordinate of a point as such: "(" Subscript[x, k] "," Subscript[y, k] ")"

But the output is something like this: (), x_k y_k

How do I write (x_k,y_k) instead?

Comment: Some context is needed. What did you do exactly, what happened, and do you expect instead? My best guess is that you want `Row`, but the question is unclear.

Comment: `pt = {1, 1}; Graphics[{Point[pt], Text[StringForm["(``, ``)", Subscript[x, k], Subscript[y, k]], pt, {-1.25, -1.25}]}]`

Comment: Those three questions were exactly the three lines I wrote in my question eheh, but thanks a lot, Row does the trick! :)